# Meaning in 'OF' in zlib function declarations

Tags: c, zlib, compression

I want to implement deflate decompression on data in C. I have a pointer to the data and compressed data length.

On going through the zlib documentation, I see all function declarations have 'OF' in between the function name and arguments list.

eg.

```
ZEXTERN int ZEXPORT inflateInit OF((z_streamp strm));
ZEXTERN int ZEXPORT deflateEnd OF((z_streamp strm));
...
```

Can someone explain what this is?
And also suggest links on working of zlib library in c

Answer (score 4):

One minute of reading the source reveals this, from  [`zconf.h`](https://github.com/madler/zlib/blob/master/zconf.h#L288):

```
#ifndef OF /* function prototypes */
#  ifdef STDC
#    define OF(args)  args
#  else
#    define OF(args)  ()
#  endif
#endif
```

Basically if the symbol `STDC` is defined, function argument lists are included in the declaration, else they are dropped and replaced with empty parentheses for old C compilers.

So the linked duplicate is exactly right, but I chose to post this anyway since this is "evidence" of the theory presented there.

Comment: Thanks. I should have gone through zconf.h